# Create a list only considering the elements of another list

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list from the elements of one list (base) but only considering the elements of another list (other).

The base list is:

```py
base = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
```

The other list is:

```py
other = ['A', 'B']
```

The expected result is:

```py
expected = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B']]
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: You'll have to write code, which it appears you have not attempted yet.

Comment: "a more pythonic way" than what?

Answer (score 1):

#### Like this:

```
base = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
other = ['A', 'B']
expected = [[i for i in l if i in other] for l in base]
print(expected)
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', 'B'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A'],
 ['B']]
```

**Breaking it down:** `expected = [[i for i in l if i in other] for l in base]` is the equivalent of:

```
expected = []

for l in base: # For every list in base
    lst = [] # There will be a list in expected
    for i in l: # For every element in l
        if i in other: # If the element is in base
            lst.append(i) # Append the element to the list that will go into expected
    expected.append(lst) # Append lst to expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
result = [[x for x in arr if x in other] for arr in base]
```

One quick optimization can be applied here. Set data structure can be used here to store `other` for the O(1) lookup.

So, the improved version:

```
otherSet = set(other)
result = [[x for x in arr if x in otherSet] for arr in base]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter`:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda f: f in other, x)), base))
```

```
[['A', 'B'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A'],
 ['B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A'],
 ['B']]
```